# Spring boot JPA resultset repeating first row of data

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using Spring boot 2 and Hibernate 5, and trying to select data from joining two tables. But, the returned result is repeating the first row of data.

```
@Autowired
private CaseDTRsServiceImpl caseDTRsService; 

@Test
public void UnitTest_findCaseByStage() {
    Iterable <CaseDTRs> caseDTRsIterable = caseDTRsService.findCaseByStage("Eligibility");

    List <CaseDTRs> CaseDTRsList = StreamSupport
        .stream(caseDTRsIterable.spliterator(), false)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());             

    for (int i=0; i<CaseDTRsList.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.printf("%d-Case Number: %d ", i, CaseDTRsList.get(i).getCaseNum());
        System.out.printf(" TypeCd: %s, getDocNumber:%s\n", CaseDTRsList.get(i).getTypeCd(), CaseDTRsList.get(i).getDocNumber());

    }

}


@Service
public class CaseDTRsServiceImpl implements CaseDTRsService {

@Autowired
private CaseDTRsRepository caseDTRsRepository;

public Iterable<CaseDTRs> findAll() {
    return caseDTRsRepository.findAll(); 
}


public Iterable<CaseDTRs> findCaseByStage(String stage) {

    return caseDTRsRepository.findCaseByStage(stage);
    //return caseDTRsRepository.findCaseByStage();

}

}


@Repository
public interface CaseDTRsRepository extends JpaRepository<CaseDTRs, String> {

@Query(value = "SELECT case_num, TYPE_CD, doc.x_doc_id_num " + 
"FROM siebel.s_case ca, siebel.s_evt_act doc " + 
"where ca.row_id=doc.x_case_id and case_num='10009999' ", nativeQuery = true)

List<CaseDTRs> findCaseByStage(String stage);

}
```

> UnitTest_CaseDTRs > Size: 75
>
> UnitTest_CaseDTRs > Case Num: 10009999 0-Case Number: 10009999 
>   TypeCd: Public Housing, getDocNumber:070123
>
> 1-Case Number: 10009999  TypeCd: Housing, getDocNumber:070123
>
> 2-Case Number: 10009999  TypeCd: Housing, getDocNumber:070123
>
> ....
>
> 74-Case Number: 10009999  TypeCd: Housing, getDocNumber:070123

Comment: if findCaseByStage() is returning a List<CaseDTRs> in CaseDTRsRepository, why the return type of findCaseByStage() in CaseDTRsServiceImpl is returning Iterable<CaseDTRs>, you can directly return List<CaseDTRs>. Try returning List<CaseDTRs>

Comment: Did you find out the cause? I experience the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the service to

```
@Service public class CaseDTRsServiceImpl implements CaseDTRsService {

@Autowired
private CaseDTRsRepository caseDTRsRepository;

public Iterable<CaseDTRs> findAll() {
    return caseDTRsRepository.findAll(); 
}


public List<CaseDTRs> findCaseByStage(String stage) {

    return caseDTRsRepository.findCaseByStage(stage);

}
}
```

Change the test case code to

```
@Autowired
private CaseDTRsServiceImpl caseDTRsService; 

@Test
public void UnitTest_findCaseByStage() {
    List <CaseDTRs> caseDTRsList = caseDTRsService.findCaseByStage("Eligibility");



    for (int i=0; i<caseDTRsList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d-Case Number: %d ", i, CaseDTRsList.get(i).getCaseNum());
        System.out.printf(" TypeCd: %s, getDocNumber:%s\n", CaseDTRsList.get(i).getTypeCd(), CaseDTRsList.get(i).getDocNumber());

    }

}
```

Comment: CNKR, that's a good catch. However, I make the changes, and test it again.  It's still repeating the first row data.  -thx

Comment: @PatL, Can you debug and see where the issue is, is it in the repository class or in the service class or in test class. If it is in the repository class, can you post the Pojo CaseDTRs and the screenshot of the query in the database helps to solve this issue.